# Getting the latest row based on partition by when only one column changes

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
COL1    COL2    KEY1    KEY2    VERSION
1       11      ABC     0       0
2       12      ABC     1       0
1       11      ABC     0       0
2       13      ABC     1       1
```

I want to get the "latest" rows using a composite key based on key1 and key2 and selecting the latest version only if `version` has changed. So in this case, I'd like to get the output of a single row, because that's the only one whose version has incremented across this composite key:

```
COL1    COL2    KEY1    KEY2    VERSION
2       13      ABC     1       1
```

I have a query that looks like this, that gives me the latest row based on version, but does not account for the version change:

```
select col1, col2
from
  select col1,
         col2,
         concat(key1, key2) as composite_key,
         row_number() over (partition BY(key1, key2) order by version desc) rank
  from partitions
) updates
where updates.rank = 1
```

```
COL1    COL2
1       11
2       13
```

What additions do I need to make to account for the version? I assume a group by at some point but I'm having a hard time getting `col1` and `col2` in this case.

Comment: You should probably add a few rows of sample data to make it more representative. What if there are more rows with version 1 after the "last" row?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `lag()` for this:

```
select col1, col2
from (select p.*,
             lag(version) over (partition by key, key order by version) as prev_version
             row_number() over (partition by key1, key2 order by version desc) as seqnum
      from partitions p
     ) p
where p.seqnum = 1 and p.prev_version <> p.version;
```